# Scroll a JTree so that last line is at top of JScrollPane in Java

Tags: java, swing, scroll

I have a large JTree (many nodes) displaying in a JScrollPane. I would like to allow the last tree node to display at the top of the JScrollPane. Swing does not seems to allow this by default, showing the (fully expanded) JTree with the last node at the bottom of the JScrollPane. The JScrollBar thumb is touching the bottom of its track.

I am using the JViewport.setViewPosition() method to set the upper-left location of the tree node to the upper-left position in the JViewport, but it refuses to do so if that would cause it to display "whitespace" at the bottom of the JTree.

I have tried manipulating the JViewport by setting the size (.setViewSize to its old value + an extra height of .getExtentSize()), but it still refuses to allow the thumb to move down, even though it is now **not** at the bottom of its track. I am adjusting the JViewport size in an event handler (.addChangeListener).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could override the preferred size of the JTree to be the default preferred size plus the extent size of the viewport minus the height of one row of the JTree.

Comment: The problem is that as soon as I set the JTree preferred size, it loses the ability to calculate its own size again with a new node expansion/collapse (See the source code for `JComponent.getPreferredSize())`.

Comment: @Ralph, I guess I wasn't explicit. I didn't mean that you should use the setPreferredSize() method. I meant that you could try overriding the getPreferredSize() method to first invoke the default implementation and then add on some extra height to account for the viewport height.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I'll try that on Monday morning.

Comment: That seems to work. I extended JTree and overrode getPreferredSize to return `super.getPreferredSize()` plus the `JViewport` extent height minus the rowHeight.

Answer (score 0):

What if you put your JTree inside a VBox with empty space at the bottom, and then wrap the VBox with the JScrollPane?